# How to say in one word: used different adjusting methods/approaches

Tags: single-word-requests

I need to write a heading for a chapter:

**Data restrictions and adjusting...*****(what word can be used here)***

Firstly, the chapter defines data restrictions used in different analyses. Secondly, the chapter describes what kind of modifications/alterations/different approaches/choices/peculiarities/ in adjusting, was used in this work.

**What would be an appropriate word here?**

Comment: Might you be taking about a [***meta-analysis**?*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta-analysis) Or just ***methodology*** in general?

Comment: How would you write the preamble to the US Constitution with one word?

Comment: "[The/An/My] Approach to Data Restriction and Adjustment".

Comment: Data "restrictions" used in different *previous* analyses? In contrast to data restrictions used in *this work*? It would be easier to address your question if you provided more information/detail/context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about "Diversified methodology of data restrictions adjustments" or "Various data restrictions adjustments' methods"?